# Python/Django - Acumulative variable with two or more models

Tags: python, django, view

Im new in python/django and first of all sorry for this dumb question... but I have a view with something like this:

```
index = 0

    try:
        TableA.objects.get(usuario=request.user)
        index = index + 1
    except TableA.DoesNotExist:
        index = index + 0

    try:
        TableB.objects.get(usuario=request.user)
        index = index + 1
    except TableB.DoesNotExist:
        index = index + 0

    [...]
```

I wanted that `index` was acumlative. I understand why this is not working. But how can i do that?

Comment: Can you also show how your models look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on your code you're probably looking for something like this:

```
index = 0

if TableA.objects.filter(usuario=request.user).count() == 1:
    index += 1

if TableB.objects.filter(usuario=request.user).count() == 1:
    index += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def my_view(request):
    index = 0

    if TableA.objects.filter(usuario=request.user).exists():
        index += 1

    if TableB.objects.filter(usuario=request.user).exists():
        index += 1

    return HttpResponse("User exists in {} tables".format(index))
```